# Set parameter list using XmlRpc

Tags: ros, xmlrpc, param-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I need to set some ros parameters where one of them is a list of strings. I'm using C++ but cannot find an example of how to do it.

I currently have a list `std::vector<std::string>` which I want to set in the ros parameter server.

From here http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Parameter%20Server I understand I need to use `XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue` to set the array.

So far I have tried:

> //agent_names is a populated std::vector of std::string

> XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue vocabulary(agent_names);

> n.setParam("vocabulary", vocabulary);

But it doesn't compile.

How do I construct an XmlRpcValue object from a std::vector?

Also, do I need to link to the XmlRpc library in my CMakeLists.txt and then import headers in my code? In that case, what do I put in my CMakeLists.txt?

Any help is greatly appreciated =)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55292/set-parameter-list-using-xmlrpc/) by [I.T](https://answers.ros.org/users/4077/i.t/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2013-02-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I finally ended up setting the parameter by using a launch file for my node.

Example:

Launch file:

```
<launch>
    <rosparam param="x_vector">[1.0, 2.0,
3.0]</rosparam>
    <node name="my_node" pkg="my_package" type="my_node" />
</launch>
```

Then in your node, get the vector like this:

```
std::vector<double> x_vec;
std::vector<double> x_vec_default = {1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0};

n.param<std::vector<double> >("x_vector", x_vec, x_vec_default);
```

And `x_vec` will hold the values given in the launch file, or the contents in `x_vec_default` if the `x_vector` is not available as a parameter (for example if launching the node without the launch file).

---

Originally posted by [I.T](https://answers.ros.org/users/4077/i.t/) with karma: 67 on 2013-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROSfc](https://answers.ros.org/users/27827/rosfc/) on 2016-09-02**:
How do you set a vector parameter in launch file ?

**Comment by [I.T](https://answers.ros.org/users/4077/i.t/) on 2016-09-12**:
@ROSfc See my updated answer. Sorry for late reply!